# Displaying results of an SPLongOperation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I am using SPLongOperation to run a lengthy operation. After completing, the gears page redirects back to the original page from which the long operation was launched. I am not able to write anything to the oriignal page using SPLongOperation.Endscript. Here is the code I am using

```
using (SPLongOperation operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page))
{
//.......................
//.......................
StringBuilder endScript = new StringBuilder();
endScript.Append("document.write('Success!!');");

operation.End(Request.Url.ToString(), SPRedirectFlags.UseSource, HttpContext.Current, String.Empty, endScript.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to write anything to the calling page, a new http request has been made to show you the page with the spinning wheel while your operation is under progress and then you're redirected back to the specified url (using a new request).

The easiest way to show a success message is to pass a specific querystring to your calling url by replacing your string.empty parameter with something like

```
operation.End(Request.Url.ToString(), SPRedirectFlags.UseSource, HttpContext.Current, "success=1");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms450341.aspx

and then on the load event, check if you have this parameter and display the relevant message (it would be better to add an item to the HttpContext.Items or doing a post instead of a get to remove the querystring but the suggested implementation will prevent you from changing your long operation call and behaviour)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, my requirement is not just posting a simple success of failure message. The long operation creates a small xml file, which I have to use to render at the page which invoked the long running operation. I was trying to accomplish this using Endscript. Due to the size of the file, I did not want to take up server resources by saving it in the session variable.

Comment: but what prevents you from doing it when the redirect is done (so when your calling page is loaded), you can check for a parameter, like the name of the file generated, and if you find it, you work on / display the xml file ? You still save it on disk if needed, with a guid for example to prevent tampering of url.

Comment: Dont want to save the file on the server. Too many files will be generated. Also, there has to be a better wasy to do it.

Comment: Well, why not implement something similar to the long running operation / job ? Something like http://encosia.com/2007/10/03/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/ that allows you to give more information than the message above the spinning wheel in SharePoint and also give you much more flexibility on the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Try an alert - that worked for me..

```
Script.Append("alert('Success!!');");
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2012/07/reporting-code-errors-when-running-code.html

```
SPLongOperation longOp = new SPLongOperation(this.Page);
StringBuilder sbErrors = new StringBuilder();
longOp.Begin();try
{
throw new Exception("Sample");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
  sbErrors.Append("An error occurred: " + ex.MEssage);
}

if
(sbErrors.Length > 0)
{
longOp.EndScript("document.getElementById('s4-simple-card-content').innerHTML = \"Errors have occurred during the submission. Details: " + sbErrors.ToString() + " \";");
}
//close the dialog if there were no errors
longOp.EndScript("window.frameElement.commitPopup();");
```